# EXC_BAD_ACCESS bug

Tags: c, xcode, debugging, cudd

I am studying the CUDD package but crashed into the EXC_BAD_ACCESS bug in the function Cudd_DumpDot (the first line below). What happened?

```
retval = fprintf(fp,"digraph \"DD\" {\n");
if (retval == EOF) return(0);
retval = fprintf(fp,"size = \"7.5,10\"\ncenter = true;\nedge [dir = none];\n");
if (retval == EOF) return(0);
```

Comment: This is called a "segfault" in Linux/Unix terminology. Most likely you are passing an illegal pointer to a FILE object to the function as the last parameter. What are you passing as parameter "fp" to the Cudd_DumpDot function, and how did you obtain it?

Comment: Thanks, I have found that fp is null. And this problem has been solved.